# Rows 'not in' and rows 'in' does not equal total rows in table

Tags: sql-server

I still have much  to learn in database work, so please be kind.

I am attempting to combine two tables that have similar data, but wanted to be sure that I wasn't duplicating any entries. I decided to use the query below to see how many names were already in the target table

```
select A.Name
From SourceTable A
where Name NOT IN
(
select B.Name
From [Production].[dbo].[DestinationTable] B
)
```

This returned 0 rows, so I assumed that every Name was already in the target table. But when I changed the query to

```
select A.Name
From SourceTable A
where Name IN
(
select B.Name
From [Production].[dbo].[DestinationTable] B
)
```

I got back about half of the total rows in the source table. How can these two totals not add up to the total number of rows in the source table? I assumed duplicate names, but the numbers still don't add up. What could I be missing here?

Comment: are names nullable?

Comment: No, names are not nullable.

Comment: are you duplicating by way of combining or combining and not duplicating?

Comment: post the scripts for both source and destination tables AND used collations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kamil's answer is a good explanation of what's going on with `IN` and `NOT IN`. But a better way to see if your destination table is missing any names from the source table would be to use a `LEFT JOIN` and check for NULL.

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT A.Name
FROM SourceTable A
LEFT JOIN [Production].[dbo].[DestinationTable] B ON A.Name = B.Name
WHERE B.Name IS NULL
```

This would return all names from your source that aren't in your destination.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting the total row count from both queries combined is because you have `NULL` values in your DestinationTable.

Generally you are ommitting checking for null values and this is the reason. You could add `OR name is null` to see it.

Check it using

```
select count(*) from destinationtable where name is null
```

---

Alternatively you could perform a `CROSS JOIN` and see for yourself where the data doesn't match and inspect why

Comment: The Name column does not allow nulls. :(

Comment: Then you need to give us a sample data to reproduce it, because right now we don't have enough info.

Comment: how would nulls in the destination table effect the count in the source table?

Comment: Prepare a sample and see for yourself. Create two tables. Add values to source, and less values to destination + null. Inspect results.

Comment: Sluggish1, compare "SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE 1 NOT IN (select NULL)" with "SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE 1 IN (select NULL)"

Comment: ok, so I created two test tables, source and destination, and added the null values to the destination table as you suggested, and noticed the same issue. That was a very interesting exercise, but there are no null names in either of the production tables that I am working with, so I still have no idea what is going on. But thank you very much for that very informative exercise.